# Why the table can't be get after jumping into another page?

Tags: javascript, html

There are two web pages on the same directory:test.html and model.html.
Here is part of js code on test.html,a function showResult was binded with 
a onclick envet.

```
function showResult(){
    location.href="model.html";  
    var _table=document.getElementById("showTable");
    for(var i=0;i<sessionStorage.length;i++){
        var newRow=_table.insertRow(0);
        var cell0=newRow.insertCell(0);
        var cell1=newRow.insertCell(1);
        vname=sessionStorage.key(i);
        vtime=sessionStorage.getItem(vname);
        cell0.innerHTML=vname;
        cell1.innerHTML=vtime;
        } 
    } 

//the body part of test.html
<input id="show"  type="button" value="show result" onclick="showResult()">
```

The model.html was as following.

```
<table id="showTable" border="2px">
    <tr>
       <th>name</th>
       <th>time</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
//the body part of model.html
<input type="button"  value="return"  onclick="window.history.go(-1)">
```

I want to read data from sessionStorage and display in table whose id is showTable.
When to click to trigger the showResult function in test.html,web page jumped from test.html into model.html,an error occur.

```
TypeError: _table is null
```

1.Two elements in seesionStorage of `test.html`.
 `a1` `5` and `a2` `6`
[image]
2.To click `show result` button on test.html ,the web page jump into `model.html`,and two elements in seesionStorage of `test.html` .
`a1` `5` and `a2` `6`  passed into new web page--model.html.
[image]
3.To see what happen in console of `model.html`.
[image]

For the example here ,sessionStorage had benn passed from test.html into model.html,but all elements on sessionStorage can't be written into table whose id  is showTable in model.html.
Why?

Why the table can't be get by `document.getElementById("showTable");` after jumping from test.html into model.html?

Comment: You have to add the code where you are using table `_table`, because the error is not thrown from the code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the line `location.href="model.html";` executes, the browser will be redirected to the model.html page and the code that follows will not be executed.

You should move all the code below to the model.html page as you can't access HTML elements from one page in another page after redirection

```
 var _table=document.getElementById("showTable");
    for(var i=0;i<sessionStorage.length;i++){
        var newRow=_table.insertRow(0);
        var cell0=newRow.insertCell(0);
        var cell1=newRow.insertCell(1);
        vname=sessionStorage.key(i);
        vtime=sessionStorage.getItem(vname);
        cell0.innerHTML=vname;
        cell1.innerHTML=vtime;
        } 
    }
```